# Are homogenous systems of equations with a trivial solution always consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

If a homogeneous system of equations has only a trivial solution , can we call it consistent ?

For example , consider

$a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=0$

$a_2x+ b_2y +c_2z=0$

$a_3x+b_3y+c_3z=0$

Regardless of the values of the coefficents, $(0,0,0)$ will always be a solution of the above system of equations. Now we make an assumption that the system has only a trivial solution. Would we call these equations consistent in that case ?

Comment: Consistency is nothing more than the existence of at least one solution. The trivial solution is a solution, so any homogeneous system is necessarily consistent.

Comment: Also  your matrix of coefficients is row equivalent to identity matrix

Comment: Thank you ! But I was confused whether (0,0,0) would classify for consistently since we call it trivial. But now I know the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *consistent* is used to describe a system that has *at least one solution*. As you mention, every homogeneous system is solved by the trivial solution. This means that every homogeneous system is consistent.