# Are systems of linear equations always consistent if they have no constants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Can anyone help me to understand? Why is it that we can always apply the trivial solution to a system of linear equations, as long as there are no constants on the right hand side. What is it about constants on the right hand side which can hypothetically prevent us from always applying at least the trivial solution?

Comment: What do you mean, "no constants?" Do you mean if all the right hand sides are zero?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you are asking what I think you are, just see what happens when you set all the unknowns to $0$. What will the right hand "constants" be then? If this is not what you are asking, [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: for reference, the meaning of "consistent": https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2868666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. If you have a system of equations of the form
$$
\sum_{1 \leqslant i\leqslant n} a_{i,j} x_i = 0 \quad (1 \leqslant j \leqslant r)
$$
then $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (0, \ldots, 0)$ is clearly a solution.

Answer (score 1):

J.-E. Pin has answered your first question; I try to answer your last one: *"What is it about constants...?"*

I think a simple example suffices, let me know if you are not convinced. Take a  "trivial system" of one equation:

$$-ax+by=3.$$ If $b$ is not zero, this becomes $$y=\frac{a}bx+\frac3b.$$

So if there "is a constant", i.e. $3$, this example shows that it is not "hypothetical"; trying to "apply the trivial solution" $x=y=0$ simply fails:

$$0=\frac{a}b\cdot 0+\frac3b.$$ As you know, visually $y=\frac{a}bx+\frac3b$ is a straight line NOT through the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

(You might consider the case $b=0$ on your own.)